# Laravel - PHP Artisan Serve - With New Project

Tags: laravel

i have a project laravel 7  located in C:\xampp\htdocs and it serve in 127.0.0.1:8000,

i create new project laravel 8 located in same folder (C:\xampp\htdocs) , now when open terminal
C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel8>php artisan serve   => Starting Laravel development server: http://127.0.0.1:8000

but it's open a previous project (laravel7) in browser [image]

Comment: Are you using virtual hosts? Or just raw path?

Comment: no, I don't use it

Comment: How your url in browser looks like?

Comment: http://localhost:8000/en/login  - in older (laravel 7)

Comment: May be you opened with another terminal/cmd and forgot to close that. Check with an another port, like `php artisan serve --port=3000` and open http://192.168.0.1:3000

Comment: yes , i serve it on sublime text 3 before i install a new project, still running  on it

Comment: I recommend you using virtual hosts - this way you can have many Laravel projects and access them via urls such as "laravel8.loc". If you wanted to change directory for an url, you just change the path in one file. Here is the link about how to set up virtual hosts - https://ultimatefosters.com/hosting/setup-a-virtual-host-in-windows-with-xampp-server.

Comment: now it's working on  http://127.0.0.1:3000/